# Pre-compiled Handlebars templates with SammyJS

Tags: handlebars.js, mustache, sammy.js

I'm having some difficulty finding whether SammyJS can natively handle pre-compiled Handlebars templates. Anybody have any insight into this?

http://sammyjs.org/docs/api/0.7.1/all#Sammy.Handlebars